# Trivial sequence: $32,21,14,\dots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

My little brother (third grade) asked me for help with this math problem on his homework, which was:

> Find the next number in the sequence $32,21,14,\dots$

I was not able to see a trivial solution, so I ran a linear regression (for an equation for $a_n$) which turned up an equation with an $r^2$ of .$98$, which (considering I had three points) was not suitable, so I ran a quadratic regression and got the polynomial $$2n^2-17n+47$$ which yielded an $r^2$ of 1, and so was a perfect fit. Therefore, I said the answer was $11$.

My question is, considering that the question assumes no knowledge of algebra, or exponents, is there a simple (recursive, maybe?) formula for the next number in the sequence?

Comment: Another possibility is $7$. Just multiply the leading digit by $7$. This is something doable by a $3$-grader.

Comment: I really like that! If you put it as an answer, I would up-vote. However, if you see my comment on Lost's post, they are expected to do operations on the numbers, not on the individual digits.

Comment: I always thought these kind of problems were silly because there is no right or wrong answer.  If you look hard enough you can make all sorts of contrived patterns.  I guess these kind of things can be "fun" but they could also be frustrating, especially for a kid.

Comment: @seth I think these problems are supposed to have a disclaimer with a modified version [Occam's Razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor), saying "among competing hypotheses, the one with the fewest operations should be selected." :P

Comment: @JuanSebastianLozanoMuñoz Then I think achille hui wins.  (although the fact that the second digit is not used is unsatisfying, but it is still the simplest explanation so far)

Comment: An alternate answer is $9$. one take the two thirds of previous number. i.e. $a_{n+1} = \lfloor 2/3 * a_n \rfloor$. This one now operates on numbers instead of just digits. Of course, everyone knows the ultimate answer should be $42$ but no one knows what is the real question.

Comment: @JuanSebastianLozanoMuñoz Since a quadratic polynomial has 3 unknowns, and we only know three terms of the sequence, it's not exactly surprising that the fit was perfect! In other words - you'll find a quadratic polynomial that goes through *any* three given points...

Comment: @fbg While that is true, what surprised me was the nice integer coefficients.

Comment: (which in hindsight aren't __that__ surprising)

Comment: The answer is obviously $-1/12$. That seems to be the result that an inordinate number of visitors here are obsessed with, so why not?

Answer (score 4):

Note that you have not proved that the pattern is what you say.  The next term could be anything and you could find a cubic that went through the four points.  There are also many other rules that could form these numbers.  Accepting the quadratic, I think that formula is fine.  Another way to indicate it is with a difference table, where each term is the difference of the two above it: $$\begin {array}&32&&21&&14&&11\\&11&&7&&3\\&&4&&4 \end {array}$$

Comment: This is a really nice way to explain it to a third-grader, "it's the difference of the differences"; no need to know calculus! (yet)

Answer (score 2):

I see a pattern of subtracting the number you get by adding the digits together, doubling the resulting sum, then adding one.

e.g. $3+2 = 5 \times 2 = 10 + 1 = 11$

$32-11 = 21$ and so on

In which case, the next term would be $3$

Comment: That is a nice pattern, but to be expressed in operations it would probably be $$a_n = a_{n-1} - \left(\left(\lfloor \frac{a_{n-1}}{10} \rfloor + \left(a_{n-1} - 10 \cdot \lfloor \frac{a_{n-1}}{10} \rfloor \right) \right) \cdot 2 + 1 \right)$$ (or something similar) which is not using elementary school- level operations.

Comment: You don't need to know that formula in order to be able to compute this; it seems pretty reasonable to me for the third grade.

Comment: Fair point, but my point is that they are expected to do operations on numbers, not work with the digits. However, for curiosity's sake, I like this pattern.

Comment: Ah alright then, that explains things.  I'll try to think of something else.

Answer (score 1):

A humble attempt:

To me doesn't seem trivial at all, but a possible pattern that comes to my mind is the following:

Let's say a number $a_1$ in the sequence is given, to get $a_2$ take $a_2=a_1+0.5$, to get $a_3$ take $a_3=a_2-0.75$. I believe this is a pattern that could be given to a third grade, even if they can't find a formal expression for the sequence.

Now, looks like we have something like $a_n=a_{n-1}+(-1)^{n}0.25n$ . If the first number is 1.5, follows 2.0, then 0.25, and then 1.0; notice anything curious?, those numbers can be written as $3/2,2/1,1/4,1/1,\dots$. So maybe this could be thinked as the nth term of the sequence being the fractional form of the number given by the rule above.

I don't know, maybe the way I'm thinking this is kinda dumb, but is the only thing that comes to my mind right now. But I insist, to me it doesn't look trivial at all.

Edit: I post this here because I added a couple of things for clarification and no longer fits in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible answers. One possible pattern is subtraction of primes leading to a finite end, yet an infinite beginning.
...
81-19=62
62-17=45 45 <-- preceding number of sub-sequence
45-13=32 32 <-- start of given sub-sequence
32-11=21 21
21- 7=14 14 <-- end of given sub-sequence
14- 5= 9  9 <-- next number of sub-sequence
9- 3= 6
6- 2= 4 <- end of sequence